# How to filter resources with multiple characteristics with related tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in MYSQL.

```
[Resources]
Id
Name
....
```

```
[Characteristics]
Id
Name
...
```

"Resources" can have multiple "Characteristics" so i made the relation in other table:

```
[RecurCaract]
Id
IdRes (Id of Resource)
IdCha (Id of Characteristic)
```

So for example i have this records with this characteristics associated:

```
    Example 1 - Car1 / Car2 / Car3 / Car4
    Example 2 - Car1 / Car3
    Example 3 - Car2 / Car3
    Example 4 - Car3 / Car4
```

I need a query to show all the Resources with Car2 and Car3 selected (both).

In this example (Example 1 and Example 3)

To search the resources with characteristic numer 25 enabled... i can use this query:

```
SELECT Resources.Name, Characteristics.Name FROM Resources LEFT JOIN RecurCaract ON (Resources.Id=RecurCaract.IdRes) LEFT JOIN Characteristics ON (Characteristics.Id=RecurCaract.IdCha) WHERE Characteristics.Id = '25'
```

But... if i need the resources with characteristics numer 25, and number 3 enabled (both)... i have the problem.

```
SELECT Resources.Name, Characteristics.Name FROM Resources LEFT JOIN RecurCaract ON (Resources.Id=RecurCaract.IdRes) LEFT JOIN Characteristics ON (Characteristics.Id=RecurCaract.IdCha) WHERE Characteristics.Id = '25' AND Characteristics.Id = '3'
```

This query don't work.

What's is the best approach?

Comment: A `JOIN` between those tables. If you're unsure how that plays out look at examples of *many-to-many* relationships and their queries.

Comment: Yes, i try with a JOIN, but i found a problem with i try to filter the "Resources" with 2 or more "Characteristics".

Comment: You may need to build out a more concrete example. This is all very abstract. Something with actual SQL semantics would help.

Comment: you could create a select statement that inner joins a table to itself.  RecurCaract1 and RecurCaract2.  RecurCaract1 is limited to resources of car2 and RecurCaract2 is limited to resources of car3

Comment: Any example @JoshGivens? (thanks)

Comment: provided one in the answers @EusebioBarriga

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.name RESOURCE, c1.name Characteristic_1, c2.name Characteristic_2 from 
RecurCaract rc1 inner join RecurCaract rc2 on rc1.resource = rc2.resource left join 
resources r on r.id = rc1.resource left join characteristics c1 on c1.id = 
rc1.characteristic left join characteristics c2 on c2.id = rc2.characteristic
where rc1.characteristic = 25 and rc2.characteristic = 3;
```

This should work for you.